# Load image with Glide to Google Maps Marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-glide

I have an issue. I use Glide 3.8.0.

I need to download image from server and put it to a marker on google maps.

```
    Glide.with(getBaseActivity())
                .load(place.getIconUrl())
                .asBitmap()
                .fitCenter()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(50,50) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resource))
                                .position(place.getLatLng()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_default_logo))
                        .position(place.getLatLng()));
                    }
                });
```

Also, i have default logo if some loading error, its size 50x50.

I test loading on 2 devices - nexus 5 and no name device (i dont know screen resolution and screen size, but size is almost same as nexus 5)

On the different device i have different size of marker logo and i experiment with

`.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(50,50)` sizes

Nexus 5, 50x50 very smaller comparing with default logo, 75x75 is smaller then default, 150x150 same as default

No name device: 75x75 same as default logo, 50x50 smaller then default

So, what can i do with Glide to make it same on the different device and as same as default logo 50x50 (default logo looks same on the different devices)

[image: Nexus 5 50x50]

[image: Nexus 5 75x75]

[image: Nexus 5 150x150]

Comment: may be help you https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling

Comment: unfortunately no, as i understood, Glide doesnt work with dp, and override works with pixels only, not dp

Comment: you can report this issues to Google at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188851&template=787413

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decided with recreate bitmap

```
Glide.with(getBaseActivity())
                .load(place.getIconUrl())
                .asBitmap()
                .dontTransform()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                        int pixels = (int) (50 * scale + 0.5f);
                        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, pixels, pixels, true);
                        markerImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        addMarker(place.getLatLng());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        markerImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_default_logo);
                        addMarker(place.getLatLng());
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Glide.with(this).load("url").listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
        override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {


          return true
        }

        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
            callmethod(resource)     //pass drawable to your method and set the drawable for marker there
            imageSource=resource
            return true
        }

    })
```

using

```
  BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(convertToBitmap(d,100,100));
  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng).icon(icon)
            .title(getString(titleResId))
            .draggable(true);
```

also for getting the bitmap from drawable

```
 public Bitmap convertToBitmap(Drawable drawable, int widthPixels, int heightPixels) {
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthPixels, heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, widthPixels, heightPixels);
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return mutableBitmap;
}
```

or you can use just

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method!

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap()
                    .load(dataSnapshot.child("dpURL").getValue(String.class))
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(origin).title(pno).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmappros(resource))));

                            if(firstload) {
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(origin,16));
                                firstload = false;
                            }else{
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(origin));
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

For bitmappros function!

```
private Bitmap bitmappros(Bitmap res){
    View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout, null);
    markerImage  = marker.findViewById(R.id.user_dp);
    markerImage.setImageBitmap(res);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    marker.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(52, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    marker.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    marker.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    marker.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(marker.getMeasuredWidth(), marker.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap2);
    marker.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap2;
}
```